# My puzzle about JDBC4.0 new feature: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

Guys,
I know there are some new features in JDBC4.0 and one of them is that you don't need to load database drivers explicitly as the JDBC API will automatically load the driver when you call getConnection(). So I just wanna test it.
BTW, I use Eclipse as my Dev Tool.

Here are my code snippets:

```
public class Test002JDBCRowSet {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String connURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.150:1521:";
    String database = "bmdw";
    String userName = "bmdw";
    String passWd = "bmdw";
    String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    String SQLStr = "select t.Empno, t.Ename, t.job, t.sal from employer t where t.sal > 1500";
    /*
    try{
        Class.forName(driver);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    */

    //Latest Method4 : Search for some data with RowSet, offline!
    RowSetFactory rsf = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
    try(
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL + database,userName,passWd);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQLStr);
            CachedRowSet cachedRS = rsf.createCachedRowSet();){
        cachedRS.populate(rs);
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("======Employee List -- Salary more than 1500======");
        System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%n","Employee No.","Employee Name","Employee Job","Employee Salary");
        try{
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.printf("%-15d%-15s%-15s%.2f%n",cachedRS.getInt(1),cachedRS.getString("ENAME"),cachedRS.getString("JOB"),cachedRS.getFloat(4));
            }
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            sqle.printStackTrace();

        }
        while(cachedRS.next()){
            System.out.printf("%-15d%-15s%-15s%.2f%n",cachedRS.getInt(1),cachedRS.getString("ENAME"),cachedRS.getString("JOB"),cachedRS.getFloat(4));

        }
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}
I got the runtime exception : 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.150:1521:bmdw

However, if I remove the comments about loading oracle driver explicitly, it works well.
And I'm sure I have already add the ojdbc14.jar into classpath.

So I don't know what happened. I'm trying to figure out how does the method 'getConnection()' works. 
I checked System.getProperties() but there is no property named 'jdbc.driver'. Even if I added it and set the value to 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'. It still doesn't work.
I checked ClassLoader.getSystemResources("META-INF/services/" + Driver.class.getName()) and I found there is only one default file :
jar:file:/D:/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/resources.jar!/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver

I has so far achieved little.
There might be some oversight in the configuration of Eclipse.
Hope anyone can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can help me ? or My question is so simple?

Comment: Check this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28109  --> `You need to have the ojdbc6.jar in your classpath environment variable in order to have JDBC 4.0 standard support.`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just reviewed my previous project code and copied the out-of-date oracle driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @kordirko and his comment. OP also seems to have confirmed that his problem is resolved because of his comment. Hopefully he gets notification of this and makes it an answer. :)

> Check this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28109 --> You need to have the ojdbc6.jar in your classpath environment variable in order to have JDBC 4.0 standard support. –  kordirko